# Push notifications through cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I perform a cloud function that is responsible for sending push notifications to mobile devices (Android or ios) previously registered from an app and that previously saved the messaging key on the server? The idea is that when there is modification of a child in the realtime a push notification is sent to the user. Thank you

Comment: There is an example of this in the Firebase documentation. I recommend studying that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you very much friend, I will see the recommended documentation